# Getting "Refused to create worker from blob" error in video.min.js when looking at Chrome console

Tags: javascript, video.js

Using 7.4.1, when I load a page with videojs on it, Chrome devtools is showing me this error:

```
Refused to create a worker from      
'blob:https://dev.culturediscovery.com/51e9879d-fa81-4044-9117-        
7328c0df4dd6' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
(anonymous) @   video.min.js:1830
(anonymous) @   video.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   video.min.js:2
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to deal with this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, but only on Mac Chrome.

Chrome on Android and Win10 both work, Mac Safari works, but Mac Chrome gives me this same error.

Comment: Same here.  Getting this in Chrome only.  Hope someone has an idea?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The error is related to [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) as traceback suggests. So if `default-src` or `worker-src` in CSP directive is present, every attempt to spawn worker in [browser that supports CSP for workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/worker-src#Browser_compatibility) must pass this directive or to throw error.

There is a special note about blob worker:

> To specify a content security policy for the worker, set a
>   Content-Security-Policy response header for the request which
>   requested the worker script itself.
>
> The exception to this is if the worker script's origin is a globally
>   unique identifier (for example, if its URL has a scheme of data or
>   **blob**). In this case, the **worker does inherit the content security
>   policy of the document or worker that created it**.
>
> *source: [MDN: CSP in workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#CSP_in_workers)*

So page (or iframe) where blob url is created has CSP directive:

```
"default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'"
```

Now consider following:

> As defined above, special URL schemes that refer to specific pieces of
>   unique content, such as "data:", **"blob:"** and "filesystem:" **are
>   excluded from matching a policy of * and must be explicitly listed**.
>
> *source: [W3: Security Considerations for GUID URL schemes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#source-list-guid-matching)*

It means that you need explicitly add `blob:` data schema to `default-src` or `worker-src`:

```
"default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob:"
```

Comment: Nice answer.  It's worth pointing out that to remove the OP's original error message, only `"worker-src blob:"` is needed; however, there may be _other_ errors that require `*`, `data:` and the others to be included as well.